# Perl regular expression at most and at least constraints for a character

Tags: regex, perl

How can I write a regex in Perl that has at least or at most constraints for a specific character? Is it possible to have such # of rule by regex?

Comment: I found that {n,} is at least for preceding char :)

Comment: [Try following a basic regex tutorial.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: Dear down voters... Be sure before you down vote, you read all the page... As you could see I give the answer for my question patially before that means I look to some tutorial. However my need to have a counter regex that counts a specific character by considering all occurrences in the string so there is nothing like that in any tutorial. Do not down vote to be mere down cotter.

Comment: @Erogol, so you mean, for example, given a string, you want to know if there are at least 3 but less than 5 'A's in the whole string?

Comment: @Ergol: Then please clarify your question.

Comment: Oh, and one more question, does it need to be a regex?  Or is a function that you can call ok?

Comment: @Erogol, can you post your solution and accept it to help others and so that this question doesn't show up in the unanswered questions list?

Answer (score 2):

See the [Perl Regex Tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Matching-repetitions):

> a{n,m} means: match at least n times, but not more than m times.
>
> a{n,} means: match at least n or more times
>
> a{n} means: match exactly n times

There are many examples and explanations there for more complicated expressions.

Comment: @Erogol I think this should be the accepted answer to your question.